# What should I consider to integrate a battery fuel gauge in my circuits?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, spi, lithium-ion, fuel-gauge

I am trying to include a fuel gauge with I2C or SPI communication to the circuits that use battery, but it is confusing for me which of all the options I should use, for example, I usually use 3.7V @ 3000mAh Li batteries -Ion so how should I select the correct fuel gauge for this battery?
I hope you can help me

Comment: I'm not sure if this is for a hobbyist or production build, but since most of the fuel gauges I see are in BGA packages and most of the rest are in no-lead packages, filtering the results by what you are comfortable soldering will narrow it down quite a bit.

Comment: I don't see how we could help you here without loooking at the rest of the schematic.

Comment: what are your other requirements? Size, manufactoring, availability, costs, synergies, etc. Does your circuit handle the charging as well? Do you already have a BMS? How precise has it to be (need for something with proper battery modelling). For example, I use a ADP5320 for a very size and power constraint project where costs do not matter.